# MySQL select with MIN() does not select all rows

Tags: php, mysql, select, min

**Background:** I'm a hobby programmer, trying to create a personal leaderboard for a racing game. This is done with a Raspberry Pi running a MariaDB. Leaderboard is scraped from another site and stored in the db. Then my personal laptimes are received with UDP from the game, and stored in the same MariaDB on the Pi. The results are shown on a php page. User can select different car and track combo on the php page. I want to display every players best (lowest) laptime for the chosen car-track combo. (Player names are offical gamertags, where no duplicates are allowed. They are all unique.)

With a SELECT statement like this, I get 84 rows, but I get all my own laptimes, and I only want to show my best laptime for that car-track combo.

```
$sqlstring1="SELECT * FROM laptimes WHERE track = '{$trackselect}' {$choice} AND carname LIKE '{$carselect}' ORDER BY laptime ASC";
```

I tried to use a SELECT like this, but then I only get 54 rows? I only have two laptimes recorded, so a bunch of laptimes from other people are not shown.

```
$sqlstring1 = "SELECT t1.* FROM laptimes t1
JOIN (
SELECT player, MIN(laptime) AS min_laptime
FROM laptimes 
GROUP BY player
) AS t2 ON t1.player = t2.player AND t1.laptime = t2.min_laptime
WHERE track = '{$trackselect}' {$choice} AND carname LIKE '{$carselect}' 
ORDER BY laptime ASC";
```

I've tried different SELECTS too, with LEFT JOIN for example.
The $trackselect and $carselect are values from dropdowns on php page, They seem to be working in both cases. $choice value is from two different buttons on php page. Button 1 sets $choice ="". Button 2 sets $choice = " AND player LIKE 'Maskmagog' ". This is used to show only my laptimes. It seems to be working.

**Question:** Why are some rows not selected in the 2nd SELECT?

Here are the top 5 output for the first SELECT:

```
1.  sel                 Ginetta G40 Junior  00:56.017   
2.  {DFRUK}michaeldimel Ginetta G40 Junior  00:56.149   
3.  Yorkshire Farmer    Ginetta G40 Junior  00:56.709   
4.  piquet              Ginetta G40 Junior  00:56.756   
5.  Oomph               Ginetta G40 Junior  00:56.981
```

and the 2nd SELECT:

```
1.  Yorkshire Farmer    Ginetta G40 Junior  00:56.709   
2.  saya777             Ginetta G40 Junior  00:57.002   
3.  Lamb4chop™          Ginetta G40 Junior  00:57.067   
4.  Jonge               Ginetta G40 Junior  00:57.250   
5.  NsGTR35             Ginetta G40 Junior  00:57.296
```

As you can see, only "Yorkshire Farmer" survives and is shown in both selects, and I don't understand why.

Here is the full php page, on Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/ALTzfm2S

**EDIT:** Thanks to comments below, I finally understand *why* the 2nd SELECT doesn't work. It first selects the players lowest laptime, regardless of track/car. Then it applies the WHERE, and the players who have their lowest laptimes set in other cars/tracks are of course removed from the result. D'oh! :)

**EDIT 2:** Well it seems I can't mark more than one answer. Both solutions seems to work, many thanks to all involved! I can't tell if one answer is better/more useful/more correct.

Comment: Have you dumped $sqlstring1 to verify it is as you espect?  I recommend using prepared statements and avoid embedded parameters into the string, use ? and pass parameters, this will take care of all the escaping for you.

Comment: It seems to me you just need the inner query with the conditions of the outer query. And you should definitely use a prepared statement.

Comment: Thank you, I'll change it to ? and pass parameters. I have echoed $sqlstring1 and it looks ok to my untrained eyes at least. I did have some trouble with the escaping, and echoing it helped me fix that. If the 2nd SELECT looks ok, then it probably is an issue with the WHERE statements? Although all entries are identical, regarding $trackselect and $carselect afaik. Some of the players are featured several times in the db (different cars-tracks), some only once. I can't see a pattern regarding those not selected vs those selected in both SELECTs.

Comment: @jeroen Thanks, I'll change to prepared statement. But for now, not sure I understand, Do you mean like this: SELECT player, MIN(laptime), WHERE track = '{$trackselect}' {$choice} AND carname LIKE '{$carselect}' 
ORDER BY laptime ASC;

Comment: @jeroen cheers, thanks! I can't actually test it right now since I'm at work and the Pi is at home, not reachable from the outside. But I'll test it as soon as I get home!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirements, you don't need nested `SELECT`'s. You can add the conditions to your inner query and use that:

```
SELECT player, MIN(laptime) AS min_laptime
FROM laptimes 
WHERE track = ?
    AND carname LIKE ?
    AND player LIKE ?
GROUP BY player
ORDER BY laptime ASC
```

If you don't need all conditions, you can build the sql statement string dynamically, adding only the ones you need. Afterwards you bind the required number of variables and execute the statement.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try as soon as I can. Also thank you for showing how to pass parameters with ? (I'm a rookie).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your subquery is returning the minimum lap time for a player *regardless of track or car*. You need it to return the minimum lap time for the player for each car on each track they have raced on, so you need to change the `GROUP BY` to

```
GROUP BY player, track, carname
```

and then you also need to add `track` and `carname` to the subquery `SELECT` and to the `JOIN`. So your query should look like:

```
$sqlstring1 = "SELECT t1.* FROM laptimes t1
JOIN (
SELECT player, track, carname, MIN(laptime) AS min_laptime
FROM laptimes 
GROUP BY player, track, carname
) AS t2 ON t1.player = t2.player AND t1.laptime = t2.min_laptime AND t1.track = t2.track AND t1.carname = t2.carname
WHERE track = '{$trackselect}' {$choice} AND carname LIKE '{$carselect}' 
ORDER BY laptime ASC";
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds very interesting. I'll try as soon as I get home.

Comment: Perhaps even car name should be included in the group by / joining condition if a player can race with multiple cars on the same track. Regardless of this, I think this answer is on the right track :)

Comment: @Shadow yes on closer reading I think you're right. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Martin I've updated my answer based on Shadow's comment which I think is correct; I don't think I had completely understood the question.

Comment: Or you could add the same filter criteria to the subquery and then you do not need group by on car and track, only on user. Or just use the subquery without the outer query with filters and add the filter values as static fields to the select list and group by on the players only.

Comment: Yes, it finally dawned on me why my SELECT doesn't work, thank you! Haven't had time to test it, but will test tonight. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this works too, if I move the WHERE to the inner query. Slightly more 'complicated' than jeroens answer, but I have a feeling this answer has other qualities. I'll mark both as answers.